# What the different about the declaring variable in For loop or out?

Tags: c#

1. Why method Calcu1 has the same code as Method Calcu2 in ILSpy while others are not?
2. Although they are different types(some of them are reference type,others are value type),why method Calcu3 is the only one has different hashcode? Are the others declare and operate the same variable?

   ```
   class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
       Calcu8();
   }

   static void Calcu1() {
       int single;
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           single = 5;
           Console.WriteLine(single + i);
       }
   }

   //Method Calcu2 has the same code as Method Calcu1 in ILSpy
   static void Calcu2() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           int single = 5;
           Console.WriteLine(single + i);
       }
   }

   //class type
   static void Calcu3() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           Student stu = new Student();
           stu.Name = "Tim";
           //not the same
           Console.WriteLine(stu.GetHashCode());
       }
   }

   //class type
   static void Calcu4() {
       Student stu = new Student();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           stu.Name = "Tim";
           //same
           Console.WriteLine(stu.GetHashCode());
       }
   }

   //string
   static void Calcu5() {
       string str = string.Empty;
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           str = "Hello";
           //same
           Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());
       }
   }

   //string
   static void Calcu6() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           string str = string.Empty;
           str = "Hello";
           //same
           Console.WriteLine(str.GetHashCode());
       }
   }

   //struct
   static void Calcu7() {
       Person per = new Person();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           per.Name = "Tim";
           //same
           Console.WriteLine(per.GetHashCode());
       }
   }

   //struct
   static void Calcu8() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           Person per = new Person {
               Name = "Tim"
           };
           //same
           Console.WriteLine(per.GetHashCode());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   public class Student {
   public string Name;
   }

   public struct Person {
   public string Name;
   }

Comment: Because the code with value type is being optimized but with reference type can't, it works differently with instantiation of `new Student()` once and in the loop body. Thus, there's difference between 1 instance against 10 instances. `struct` not by-ref type and it behaves as `int` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me point out the difference between your methods:

Method `Calcu1`, `Calcu4`, `Calcu5`, `Calcu7`: The variable has been declared outside and set inside the loop. The value will be present outside the loop.

Method `Calcu2`, `Calcu3`, `Calcu6`, `Calcu8`: The varibale has been declared inside the loop and will not be available outside.

Your hashCode of `Calcu3` changing, because you are creating each time a different object. By creating an `Student` via new, the stack will have an reference to an new object on the heap. This reference is changing every time, because you are creating 10 new objects.

Your hashCode of `Calcu8` is not the same, because it is a `struct` and structs are saved on the heap.

See [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/stack-vs-heap-memory-c-sharp/) for further information about stack an heap. On this side, you also find a definition what goes on the heap an on the stack.

On the stack:

> "Things" declared with the following list of type declarations are Value Types
> (because they are from System.ValueType):
> bool, byte, char, decimal, double, enum, float, int, long, sbyte, short, **struct**, uint, ulong, ushort

On the Heap:

> "Things" declared with following list of type declarations are Reference Types
> (and inherit from System.Object... except, of course, for object which is the System.Object object):
> class, interface, delegate, object, string

Comment: Thanks a lot,bro.But I still have a couple of questions. 1.hashcode of Calcu8 is the same in my test and also supported by your words "because it is a struct and structs are saved on the heap."   2. Why ValueType cannot saved on the heap again and again in the for loop?

Comment: Value types _may_ be allocated on the stack or the heap. Reference types can not be stack allocated.